# Change component's template Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-mdl

I'm using mdl-select component. It's a drop-down list. When you press it there are `focusin` event fired. But it doesn't when you press an arrow-dropdown icon, so I needed to change a template a bit to have a desired behavior. But it's a library component. Is there a way to override it's template?

The thing I need to change just to add `tabindex=\"-1\"` to element. I can do it with js, but I use component a lot in app, and I don't want to use `document.getElement...` every time I use `MdlSelectComponent` in the views of my own components.

I tried to use `@Component` decorator function on `MdlSelectComponent` type, however it requires to declare this class once again and anyway have done nothing.

### Update

*main.browser.ts*

```
/*
 * Angular bootstraping
 */
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { decorateModuleRef } from './app/environment';
import { bootloader } from '@angularclass/hmr';

import {MdlSelectComponent} from '@angular2-mdl-ext/select';
/*
 * App Module
 * our top level module that holds all of our components
 */
import { AppModule } from './app';

/*
 * Bootstrap our Angular app with a top level NgModule
 */
export function main(): Promise<any> {
  console.log(MdlSelectComponent)
  MdlSelectComponent.decorator.template = "<div class=\"mdl-textfield is-upgraded\" [class.is-focused]=\"this.popoverComponent.isVisible || this.focused\" [class.is-disabled]=\"this.disabled\" [class.is-dirty]=\"isDirty()\"> <span [attr.tabindex]=\"!this.disabled ? 0 : null\" (focus)=\"open($event);addFocus();\" (blur)=\"removeFocus()\"> <!-- don't want click to also trigger focus --> </span> <input #selectInput tabindex=\"-1\" [readonly]=\"!autocomplete\" class=\"mdl-textfield__input\" (click)=\"toggle($event)\" (keyup)=\"onInputChange($event)\" (blur)=\"onInputBlur()\" [placeholder]=\"placeholder ? placeholder : ''\" [attr.id]=\"textfieldId\" [value]=\"text\"> <span class=\"mdl-select__toggle material-icons\" (click)=\"toggle($event)\"> keyboard_arrow_down </span> <label class=\"mdl-textfield__label\" [attr.for]=\"textfieldId\">{{ label }}</label> <span class=\"mdl-textfield__error\"></span> <mdl-popover [class.mdl-popover--above]=\"autocomplete\" hide-on-click=\"!multiple\" [style.width.%]=\"100\"> <div class=\"mdl-list mdl-shadow--6dp\"> <ng-content></ng-content> </div> </mdl-popover> </div> ";

  return platformBrowserDynamic()
    .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .then(decorateModuleRef)
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
}

// needed for hmr
// in prod this is replace for document ready
bootloader(main);
```

`APP.COMPONENT.TS`

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
require('../../../styles/styles.scss');
import {MdlSelectComponent} from '@angular2-mdl-ext/select';
//
declare let Reflect: any;
Reflect.getOwnMetadata('annotations', MdlSelectComponent)[0].template = 'Hooray';
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    styleUrls: [],
    template: `
        <div>
            <mdl-select [(ngModel)]="personId">
                <mdl-option *ngFor="let p of people" [value]="p.id">{{p.name}}</mdl-option>
            </mdl-select>
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>`
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(
        router: Router,
    ) {
        router.events.subscribe(data => {
            scrollTo(0, 0);
        });
    }

    public ngOnInit() {
    }
}
```

Comment: You can copy paste the component with your own name and add the functionality you desire. SInce you are using angular2-mdl it should be very easy

Comment: @Skeptor Peatifully, it's not an option. Component uses a lot of inner library dependences, and it's not a single component from the library I use. As a case I can override that file with a help of webpack, but I wanted to know if I can just redecorate it with a new template for example in `app.component.ts`/

Comment: Try if you can do something like `MdlSelectComponent.decorator.template =''` inside `main.ts`. Since its all mdl , you can write your own html with appropriate classes just for that component and build your own component

Comment: @Skeptor Have done this (see update) but is says there'is no decorator property on this type. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `@angular2-mdl-ext/select` uses `Reflect` to define decorators then you do the following

```
declare let Reflect: any;
Reflect.getOwnMetadata('annotations', MdlSelectComponent)[0].template = 'Hooray';
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/DGh697e997TQnJrEo1Mn?p=preview)**

Comment: Hi, thanks you very mush for replay. I've inserted the following lines in my `app.module.ts` file as you did in planker, however still can't get it to work - template doesn't change( Have tried with `main.ts` and `app.component.ts` as well. You can see `app.component.ts` in updates. What have I done wrong?

Comment: @K.Rice How do you build your project? Maybe you can put up a github repo with minimal reproduction?

Comment: Thanks for repo. You are overriding another component with the same name `import { MdlSelectComponent } from '@angular2-mdl-ext/select';`

Comment: But you use component from `import { MdlSelectModule, MdlSelectComponent } from '@angular-mdl/select';`

Comment: So remove `import { MdlSelectComponent } from '@angular2-mdl-ext/select';` and import `MdlSelectComponent` from `@angular-mdl/select`

Comment: Oh, I see. Replaced with a proper component and now works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to hear! :)